# Singleton pattern in web applications

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, singleton

I'm using a singleton pattern for the datacontext in my web application so that I dont have to instantiate it every time, however I'm not sure how web applications work, does IIS open a thread for every user connected? if so, what would happend if my singleton is not thread safe? Also, is it OK to use a singleton pattern for the datacontext? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with creating a new data context for each request?  Sounds like you're prematurely micro-optimizing at the cost of increasing coupling and decreasing testability and flexibility.

Comment: I just read somewhere that class instantiation was expensive in terms of performance, so I was trying to avoid it using a lazy singleton, but I guess is not the best way for what I have read in the responses.

Comment: +1 on optimizing too early. You are better off just doing a smart implementation and then looking for the bottle necks later. Just as a side note, keep in mind that every time a user hits your site there are many, many classes getting created and destroyed (you would probably be very surprised if you could see it all happen!)

Comment: I don't know where this "somewhere" is where people keep reading that class instantiation is expensive.  I really wish I could contact the original author of said piece and tell him to go pound sand.  This singular bad idea seems to lead to more awful designs than any other.  Please exercise a healthy skepticism toward everything you read on the internet - including this comment.

Comment: @Aaronaught http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#performance

Comment: @Superstringcheese And? Where does Skeet say that newing is expensive? Is there some point you're trying to make by dropping that link?

Comment: @Aaronaught I had misread Skeet's point about checking that the singleton had been loaded (say, in a tight loop) getting expensive. I realize now that this is irrelevant to the discussion; I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many people keep the DataContext around for the duration of the request by keeping it in the `HttpContext.Current.Items` Thereby it is also private to the request.

Have a look at [this blogpost by Steve Sanderson](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/11/29/linq-to-sql-the-multi-tier-story/), and the [UnitOfWork patter](http://takacsot.freeblog.hu/Files/martinfowler/unitOfWork.html)n.

Answer (score 14):

> I'm using a singleton pattern for the datacontext in my web application

"Singleton" can mean many different things in this context.  Is it single-instance per request?  Per session?  Per thread?  Per AppDomain (`static` instance)?  The implications of all of these are *drastically* different.

A "singleton" per request (stored in the `HttpContext`) is fine.  A singleton per session is discouraged, but can be made to work.  A singleton per thread may appear to work but is likely to result in unexpected and difficult-to-debug behaviour.  A singleton per Application or AppDomain is a disaster waiting to happen.

> so that I dont have to instantiate it every time

Creating a `DataContext` is very, very cheap.  The metadata is globally cached, and connections aren't created until you actually execute a query.  There is no reason to try to optimize away the construction of a `DataContext` instance.

> however I'm not sure how web applications work, does IIS open a thread for every user connected?

IIS uses a different thread for every request, but a single request may use multiple threads, and the threads are taken from the Thread Pool, which means that ultimately the same user will have requests on many different threads, and conversely, different users will share the same thread over multiple requests and an extended period of time.  That is why I mention above that you cannot rely on a Thread-Local Singleton.

> if so, what would happend if my singleton is not thread safe?

Very bad things.  Anything that you cache globally in an ASP.NET application either needs to be made thread safe or needs to be locked while it is in use.

> Also, is it OK to use a singleton pattern for the datacontext? Thanks.

A `DataContext` is not thread-safe, and in this case, even if you lock the `DataContext` while it is in use (which is already a poor idea), you can still run into cross-thread/cross-request race conditions.  Don't do this.

`DataContext` instances should be confined to the scope of a single method when possible, using the `using` clause.  The next best thing is to store them in the `HttpContext`.  If you must, you can store one in the Session, but there are many things you need to be aware of (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383966/entity-framework-object-context-in-asp-net-session-object/2384752#2384752) I answered recently on the `ObjectContext` - almost all of the same principles apply to a `DataContext`).

But above all, **do not** create "global" singleton instances of a `DataContext` in an ASP.NET application.  You will deeply regret it later.

Comment: I had an Application-Singleton of a DataContext, and it was nothing but trouble. Race conditions, _enormous_ amounts of data getting pinned to the heap, and a slew of inexplicable errors.

Comment: This isn't confined to ORMs either; I recently inherited some old-school ADO.NET code that used a `static` connection object. Impossible to unit test and failed the WCF integration tests instantly.  I've never understood what compels people to do this; connection pooling has been part of ADO.NET since its inception so it honestly does not matter how many logical instances you create.

Answer (score 7):

Static variables are visible to all users on the per app domain, not per session. Once created, the variable will sit in memory for the lifetime of the app domain, even if there are no active references to the object.

So if you have some sort of stateful information in a web app that shouldn't be visible to other users, it should absolutely *not* be static. Store that sort of information in the users session instead, or convert your static var to something like this:

```
public static Data SomeData
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Session["SomeData"] == null)
            HttpContext.Session["SomeData"] = new Data();
        return (Data)HttpContext.Session["SomeData"];
    }
}
```

It *looks* like a static variable, but its session specific, so the data gets garbage collected when the session dies and its totally invisible to other users. There safety is not guaranteed.

Additionally, if you have stateful information in a static variable, you need some sort of syncronization to modify it, otherwise you'll have a nightmare of race conditions to untangle.

Answer (score 1):

@ryudice the web server creates a new thread for each request. I think the best approach is to have a datacontext bound to each request, meaning that you should create a new datacontext every time you serve a request. A good way of achieving this is by using a DI tool, such as [StructureMap](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/Default.htm). These kind of tools allow you to setup the lifecycle of the instances you configure, so for example in your case you would configure your XDataContext class to be HttpContext scoped.

Regards.

Comment: Not to be nitpicky--just want to clarify something--the web server is definitely not creating a new thread to service each request. In some ways it feels like it, but in many others it doesn't (because that's not what happens)

Comment: Your recommendation to create a new datacontext for each request is good, though--dataContext is pretty lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

here are Microsoft's examples on how to do multi-tier with LINQ-To-SQL.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/multitierlinqtosql