# How do I make my WCF proxy asp.net session-dependent?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis

I have a (hand-coded) WCF proxy layer (i.e. not a ServiceReference) that handles all client-side functionality and does some caching for a WCF application (served under IIS 7). I can run, say, two desktop clients, and each one will have its own proxy, and their cached objects (some of which are static or singleton) will function independently, since each proxy runs in its own process, of course.

Now, I have an asp.net MVC website (not a technology I know well), and I want this same behavior: when two different clients connect to the web server, I want two different instances of the proxy. I'm assuming this has something to do with asp.net sessions, but don't know where to go next to hook up the asp.net session and the proxy instance. Is there a way to do this out of the box?

Put another way, how do I make an IIS server under asp.net use a WCF proxy as a client, and not treat it as a server?

Comment: How are you creating instances of the proxy?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Not sure what you mean by "creating instances". A given channel is opened via a channel-factory type pattern inside the proxy layer. But while the proxy layer assembly resolves to a dll, it's not OOP. Adding a reference just allows the client to use those channels and contracts. (The application is "WCF on both sides".)

Comment: Is your proxy layer a static class? How do you open a channel?

Comment: @JohnSaunders The proxy layer uses a static class to cache and to spin off channels. Basically, a UI method asks the (static) factory for a proxy wrapper (so I'm not deriving the WCF proxies from ClientBase), the (static) factory generates it and opens the channel, the proxy wrapper makes the channel call(s), and the UI asks the factory to close/dispose that wrapper. The assemblies look something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114139/WCF-The-Right-Way-A-Quick-Reference-Guide

Comment: FYI: very dangerous using statics in a web application - they are **Not** per-session, they are across all sessions, and are accessed by multiple threads at a time. If you don't do locking properly, you've got a major problem on your hands.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I hear you. Wasn't originally intended to be a web app, hence the original question. Even if I were to turn that factory into an instance, I still don't see how to tie the proxy into per-session behavior. The web session should be firing calls off to the *WCF app service* (it should *be the proxy*), but out of the box it's firing them *at* the WCF client (treating it as a server).

Comment: You are not using ASP.NET session state right now. If you mean "session" in some other sense, then you should be more specific. If the proxy were an instance, then you could use ASP.NET session state to store instances of the proxy in session state. The code would refer to it as `((MyProxyType) Session["ProxyInstance"]).OpenChannel()` or whatever. You would _still_ have to be careful about any cached data stored in statics, as there would _still_ be one copy of that data for all users and sessions.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I do mean web (asp, http, whatever) session, yes. I follow that last comment mostly, and it may well be the answer I'm looking for (not my area of expertise, so don't know yet). I understand the static problem. Don't really understand what `"ProxyInstance"` is a reference to though.

Comment: It's not a reference. Session state is accessed through a dictionary. `"ProxyInstance"` is simply the key I chose to use to access the instance stored in session state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you can refactor your code such that your proxy is an instance, you would be able to use something like the following to access it in the ASP.NET application:

```
public class WcfProxy
{
    private WcfProxy(){}

    private static object _locker = new object();

    public static WcfProxy Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ProxyInstance"] == null)
                {
                    lock (_locker)
                    {
                        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ProxyInstance"] == null)
                        {
                            HttpContext.Current.Session["ProxyInstance"] = new WcfProxy();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return (WcfProxy) HttpContext.Current.Session["ProxyInstance"];
            }
        }
    }

    public void OpenChannel(){}
}
```

Note that this omits locking. Usage:

```
WcfProxy.Instance.OpenChannel();
```

Comment: It should be good with my last edit. I _do_ prefer to look at multi-threaded code for more than 5 minutes, though...

Comment: Fair enough. Was just wondering about comments [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2399030/409856) that seem to indicate that a per-session asp service doesn't necessarily play well with them.

Comment: I don't know why he feels singleton per session is discouraged. Certainly you will need your object to be serializable if you use out of process or database-based session state. In fact, once you've turned your proxy into an instance, you should really consider disabling the caching and just creating an instance whenever you need it. You should then profile the performance - it's possible that you don't need to cache as much as you think you do.

Comment: So now that I've had a chance to play with this some... Yes, this solves the web problem. But it breaks my existing app instance, which needs a proper singleton implementation (storing a volatile single instance field), and doesn't use HttpContext. Is there some way to do both in the same proxy, still using the singleton pattern?